# mongodb java driver query with regexp number fields

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm trying to convert this query in java:

```
db.beni.find({ $where: function() {
  return /.*11/.test(this.foglio) || /.*99/.test(this.comune) } })
```

Where this.foglio is a numeric field and this.comune is a string fields.

Thanks

Comment: Found!
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.append("$where", new Code("function() {return /.*11/.test(this.foglio) || /.*99/.test(this.comune)}"));

Comment: can you explain more? where is `Code` defined?

Comment: simply with the code class (http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/org/bson/types/Code.html) you are able to use the above js syntax with the java driver.

Comment: Did that work for you devmao? Can you post it as an answer and then accept it youself? Thanks.